# How to create a shortcode for custom page template?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a custom page template and I want it to display on specific pages. The only way I know to do this is to create a shortcode, but I don't know how doing this.

I saw some article about this, but I forgot the website link.

How to create a shortcode for custom page template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved now, by adding this snippet in functions.php

```
function my_form_shortcode() {
ob_start();
get_template_part('my_form_template');
return ob_get_clean();   
} 
add_shortcode( 'my_form_shortcode', 'my_form_shortcode' );
```