# How to create a shortcode for Woocommerce view-order template?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to create a shortcode for `view-order.php` template, which is located in my child theme `/woocommerce/myaccount/view-order.php` or can be accessed via url `/my-account/view-order/{id}/` I've read this article [How to create a shortcode for custom page template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227444/how-to-create-a-shortcode-for-custom-page-template) and adjusted the code as below:

```
function view_order_shortcode() {
   ob_start();
   get_template_part('view-order');
   return ob_get_clean();   
} 
add_shortcode( 'view_order_shortcode', 'view_order_shortcode' );
```

Then I insert `<?php echo do_shortcode("[view_order_shortcode]"); ?>` into a template where I want it to display but it's not working.

I read this article as well [Woocommerce - How to show Order details (my-account) on a separate page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217866/woocommerce-how-to-show-order-details-my-account-on-a-separate-page/48226043) but this one talks about `my-orders.php` The code below works fine.

```
function woocommerce_orders() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
         return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); 
    }else{
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-orders.php', array(
            'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', $user_id),
            'order_count'   => $order_count
         ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_orders', 'woocommerce_orders');
```

However, I've adjusted it to bellow but it's not working. Any suggestion?

```
function woocommerce_orders() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
         return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); 
    }else{
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/view-order.php', array(
            'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', $user_id),
         ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_orders', 'woocommerce_orders');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**view-order.php** template requires two parameters to get it to work.

1. order
2. order_id

In your example, this should work.

```
function woocommerce_view_order($params) {
    $order_id = $params['order_id'];  // get order id from shortcode params
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
         return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); 
    }else{
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/view-order.php', array(
            'order' => wc_get_order($order_id), // add this line
            'order_id' => $order_id //add this line
         ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_view_order', 'woocommerce_view_order');
```

Then, apply the shortcode with an order id: 
Example: `[woocommerce_view_order order_id=103]`